# File not found Error when uploading files and moving them

Tags: python, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, upload

I'm trying to build a selenium python script to upload files to a website.

However, I encounter random errors while uploading. The script works by using a for loop to loop through a folder of pdf files and uploads them. After the upload, the file gets moved to the "done" folder. However, I have random errors that sometimes the files could not be found. For some reason this can happen any time or not at all. Sometimes the script uploads 100s of files without crashing and sometimes it crashes at the fifth file. I tried to give it plenty of time between moving the old file and starting to upload the new one but this doesn't help either.

This is my script so far:

```
# ------------------------------ Start of For Loop -----------------------------------------

for file in os.listdir(folderpath):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        # Extract the required information from the filename
        match = re.search(r"(\d{3,5})(-)(\d{4})(-)(\d{4})(-)(\d{2})(-)(\d{2})(.*)", file)
        if match:
            filename = match.group(0)
            filepath = os.path.join(folderpath, file)
            # Construct variables

            try:
                # code that navigates to upload button

                time.sleep(2)
                pyautogui.write(filepath)
                time.sleep(4)
                pyautogui.press('enter')
                time.sleep(5)


               # code that manipluates Metadata of that file

                time.sleep(3)

                shutil.move(filepath, done_folder)

                time.sleep(6)


                # Logging of the file Upload
                timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                logging.info(f"{timestamp} - File '{filename}' uploaded succesfully.")
                time.sleep(5)

                    

            except Exception as e:
                timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                logging.warning(f"{timestamp} - An error occurred during the upload of file '{file}': {str(e)}")
                error = True
                shutil.move(filepath, error_folder)
                break
```

The problem is that I can't enter the file path to the site but I can just press the upload button. when I press that button the standard Windows file selector window opens. Since the field of the file selector gets automatic autofocus I just use py autogui to write the whole filepath in the field and press enter. Since there is an implicit wait defined it waits for the Upload.

So what should happen is that the for loop takes the first file then uploads it and then moves it to the "done" folder, then take the next file, and so on. The thing is 90% of the time it works exactly like that. But sometimes at random intervals, the script crashes cause I get an error that the file hasn't been found.

I'm not a really good programmer so maybe I do not fully understand all the functions I use like os.listdir(folderpath), shutil.move(filepath, done_folder) or for loops in general. Maybe moving stuff around while looping through them doesn't work that way. But I would like to know which file got uploaded successfully and which was raised in error.

I appreciate any tips on how to make this code better.

Thank you.